# Call component inside component October CMS gives an error

Tags: php, components, extend, octobercms

I am trying to extend an existing plugin component and I
need to add a function but use plugins methods.

Here what I have:

```
<?php namespace Bbrand\Shop\Components;

use Cms\Classes\ComponentBase;
use Jiri\JKShop\Components\Basket;


class Shopextend extends ComponentBase
{

    public function componentDetails()
    {
        return [
            'name'        => 'shopextend Component',
            'description' => 'No description provided yet...'
        ];
    }

    public function defineProperties()
    {
        return [];
    }


    public function onBasket(){

        $data = [];
        $data["basket"] = Basket::getSessionBasket();
        $data["jkshopSetting"] = \Jiri\JKShop\Models\Settings::instance();

        return [ 
            $this->property("idElementWrapperBasketComponent") => $this->renderPartial('@basket-0', $data) 
        ];

    }


}
```

But I'm getting an error

> "Non-static method Jiri\JKShop\Components\Basket::getSessionBasket()
>   should not be called statically" on line 30 of
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/fidgycube.co/plugins/bbrand/shop/components/Shopextend.php

Any help!?
thanks

Comment: calling static == `::`, not in this case means `->`

Comment: so how can i call it?!

Comment: The answer should be staring you in the face, even without my comment... it is the basics of PHP OOP. `$data["basket"] = Basket::getSessionBasket();` is being called statically, the error message clearly states **not** to do that. Now read my first comment.

Comment: very helpful! u smart, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to add component first.

```
<?php namespace Bbrand\Shop\Components;
class Shopextend extends ComponentBase
{
    public function init()
    {
        // Add component
        $this->addComponent('\Jiri\JKShop\Components\Basket', 'basket', []);
    }
}
```